# How to store variables in Django database field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I've been trying to figure out if it's possible to store a variable in a Django database field. Here is an example:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
```

And then in the HTML form field, someone inputs something like this:

```
Hi {{ user.first_name }}, thanks for signing up to our {{ company.name }} newsletter.
```

That then gets saved to the database, and when an email goes out, those fields are automatically populated with the appropriate data.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *sort of* a solution, it's not storing the variable in the Model..
But you can render plain strings with the template engine.. **but** you need to somehow fill the context / pass the user object + company - so this is halfway solution

```py
from django.template import Template, Context
from django.core.mail import send_mail

# Fetch Message Obj
msgObj = Message.objects.all().first()

print(msgObj.message) 
# Hi {{ user.first_name }}, thanks for signing up to our {{ company.name }} newsletter.

# I added a user field to message, just for ease in this example
print(msgObj.user) 


# Set msg Contents as a Template
emailtemplate = Template(msgObj.message)

# The hard part, set the context. 
data = {
    'user': msgObj.user,
    }
if 'company' in msgObj.message: # If, so we're not fetching data that's not needed (a regex like ~ '{{ keywork.[a-zA-Z0-8]+ }}' would be better)
    # company in message, get user's company
    data['company'] = msgObj.user.company_set.first()

# Use Template Engine to Render with Context
emailtext = emailtemplate.render(Context(data))

print(emailtext)
# Hi Neal, thanks for signing up to our TestCompany newsletter.

send_mail(
    'Test Message',         # subject
    emailtext,              # contents
    None,                   # from
    ['test@example.com'],   # to
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

**Per the context:** You can use:

- A combination of hardcoded commonly used keywords or Objects
- Use extra fields in the message Obj to fetch other data (like company)
- You could pass the context to the function when the mail is being sent (like the user)

Hopefully you find some of this useful. It was interesting to look into, test and learn. Ty for the question!

Comment: I think this is a great example. I think the key to this solution is to make sure it's well defined and documented since it will be customer facing.

Comment: If you don't want to use the template engine method, you could also do it by formatting strings;
I answered a very similar question a week or so ago, maybe you'd prefer that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74226432/django-call-variable-on-input-user-text/74227311#74227311
*(Also the pointer/dictionary thing is a game changer, I use it for dynamic filtering: so good)*

Answer (score 0):

It's an obvious use for a `models.JSONfield`. Store/ retrieve/ update

```
instance.variables = { variable1_name: variable_1 value, ... }
```

and you can fill out a template such as `"hello {first_name}"` with

```
try:
    template.format( **instance.variables )
except KeyError as e:
    # one or more {var} in the template string didn't have a definition 
    # in instance.variables
    print( e.args ) # is a tuple of these undefined key names.
```

Comment: The problem is that the user would have to define the variable. What I'm looking for is using already defined variables in Django, like request.user.first_name

Comment: You can do `instance.variables = some_form.cleaned_data`, in which case your form defines what are acceptable variable names (ie the form field names). Also to accumulate multiple forms, `instance.variables.update( some_form.cleaned_data)`