# Django - Call variable on input user text

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a excel data with multiple colums, inside the I have a name colum, now by HTML input the user can write a custom text.

I need that the user can use something to call name variable when he like.

If use f'User cutsom text {name}' or something like that not work, django keep input user text like a text.

Do you know a possibility.

I need that the user can use or call variables from the excel when he write his text

Comment: And how do you read that excel data (There are multiple ways to read excel files in python)? Plus why even make this a Django problem? Isn't this simply "How to read an excel column specified by the user?" Don't add tags to your question just because you use the technology, tags help you connect to subject matter experts relevant to your problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: HI Abdul I read excel with Panda, i like for example user input 'Hi %NAME% i hope your well. I like to have a online meeting with you. %NAME% its possible tomorrow?" and with view or something like that change %NAME% by the real name on excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question isn't very clear, but based on `f'User cutsom text {name}'` I assume you are posting HTML input data to a view and then using python to read in a CSV.. there is a way to dynamically format strings

###### Pre-Knowlege

You can dynamically pass any kwargs to any function using `**{keyword: value}` *(this is super useful)*
Here's a basic example using this for formatting strings:

```py
tmp_str = 'User custom text {name}'

tmp_dict = {'name': 'Neal'}

new_str = tmp_str.format(**tmp_dict)
 
print(new_str) # 'User custom text Neal'

# Note: Having extra keys in the Dictionary is fine
#   it doesn't raise an error if it's not in the string
```

###### View Example

And expanding this idea, here's an example view

```py
def temp(request):
    if request.method == 'POST'

        # Get String from HTML Input that was POSTed
        formated_string = request.POST.get('some_formated_string')

        # Raw String that was POSTed
        print(formated_string) # '{name} Looks {looks}'

        # Get a Row's Data in a dictionary 
        #   key= header_name/variable_name, value= row+col data
        csv_row_data = {
            'name': 'Neal',
            'intelligence': 'incredible',
            'looks': 'outstanding',
        }

        end_value = formated_string.format(**csv_row_data)

        # formated_string.format(**csv_row_data)
        #   runs the same as:
        # '{name} Looks {looks}'.format(name='Neal', intelligence='incredible', looks='outstanding')

        print(end_value) # 'Neal Looks outstanding'
        # Dynamic String Formatting Successful, do something with end_value
```

The hardest part probably will be getting the row data into a dictionary. If you are using the CSV package, each row usually comes as an array.
You'll either have to hardcode it like the block below or somehow dynamically set them based on the headers

```py
for row in csv_reader:
        csv_row_data = {
            'name': row[0],
            'intelligence': row[1],
            'looks': row[2],
        }
        end_value = '{name} Looks {looks}'.format(**csv_row_data)
```

It also might be a good idea to show **valid** variables that user's can use on the webpage too.

Comment: Nealium, very very very thanks, this exactly that I need, its perfect and works for me. I appreciatte your help so much